# What is the difference between opengl and opengles?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es-2.0

Although I have been writen some code of OpenGL and OpenGL ES and I know that OpenGL ES is a subset of OpenGL and it is designed for Embedded system.
Now there's a fact that rk3399 supports OpenGL ES but not supports OpenGL.
I use OpenGL and OpenGL ES to achieve the code of getting image from camera and display it separaly.
However OpenGL ES version's frame rate is about 20fps while OpenGL version's frame rate only is about 5fps.
My assumption is that OpenGL ES's implementation is totally different from OpenGL, so rk3399 have OpenGL ES driver but not have OpenGL driver.
Is my assumption right? If not, how could I explain the performance gap bewteen above two code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which OpenGL version and how do you choose between OpenGL vs OpenGL ES?

Comment: OpenGL version is 3.0 and OpenGL ES version is 3.0.